# I cannot get the full description of a YouTube video when using YouTube API v3

Tags: youtube-data-api

In order to retrieve the full description of a youtube video, I used these codes to process.

```
String apiKey = properties.getProperty("youtube.apikey");
        search.setKey(apiKey);
        search.setQ(queryTerm)
        search.setFields("items(id/kind,id/videoId,snippet(title,description))");
```

`if (rId.getKind().equals("youtube#video")) {

```
            System.out.println(" Video Id: " + rId.getVideoId());
            System.out.println(" Title: " + singleVideo.getSnippet().getTitle());
            System.out.println(" Description: " + singleVideo.getSnippet().getDescription());
            System.out.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        }`
```

But the results cannot get the full description. If the description is too long, it will cut the tail part only shows "...". like this  Description: Learn more about Heroes of the Storm and PLAY FREE here: http://heroesofthestorm.com Facebook: http://facebook.com/BlizzHeroes Twitter: ...

I am wondering how to revise my code and get the full description

Answer (score 2):

I believe the truncation of the description is a feature of the Search:List call rather than something that occurs in the Java API. You can see this by doing the call direct from the [reference documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#try-it).

One way to get the description is to concatenate all the video IDs that you get back from the search and call [Videos:List](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) with the `id` field set to the list. In Java:

```
    YouTube.Videos.List list = youtube.videos().list("id, snippet");
    list.setKey(apiKey);
    list.setId(ids);
    List<Video> videos = list.execute().getItems();
```

Where the variable `ids` is a comma delimited list of the IDs you got from your search query.

You can then access `.getSnippet.getDescription` on each video to get the full description:

```
    for (Video targetVideo : videos) {
        System.out.println(targetVideo.getSnippet().getDescription());
    }
```